# Как определить букву подключенной флешки?

Tags: windows, delphi-7, usb

Нужно скопировать файл на флешку, а для этого необходимо указать путь куда копировать , но буквы все время разные у флешек, как определеить какая буква у флешки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала получить список всех дисков в в системе, а по событию подключения смотреть какая буква добавилась.

Вот код поиска первой флешки

```
    function FindFirstRemovableDrive: string;
var
  drive: string;
  c:     char;
begin
  for c := 'D' to 'Z' do
  begin
    drive := c + ':\';
    Log(drive + ' ' + GetDriveTypeStr(c));
    case GetDriveType(PChar(drive)) of
      DRIVE_REMOVABLE:
      begin
        Result := drive;
        Exit;
      end;
      DRIVE_UNKNOWN:
      begin
        Result := '';
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  Result := '';
end;
```

Comment: Я нашел вариант попроще

     procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
         var
          Drive: Char; //Буква диска
        const
          pref = ':\';
        begin
        
          for Drive := 'B' to 'Z' do
            if GetDriveType(PChar(Drive + pref)) = DRIVE_REMOVABLE then Caption:=Drive+ pref;
        end;

Comment: посмотри мой и свой код, и поймешь что они одинаковы.